# Replace dot with comma, and comma with dot

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to replace dots with commas and commas with dots. The data is not always the same length. I created a button (Form controls) for the code.

I tried writing the code for replacing dots with commas. The code works for replacing dots with commas. However Excel gets stuck. How do I add the part to replace commas with dots?

```
Sub ReplacePointWithComma()

Dim Cell As Range

ActiveSheet.Range("D:I").Select

For Each Cell In Selection
    Cell.Value = Replace(Cell.Value, ",", ".")
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You're iterating every single cell in 6 columns - that's 6,291,456 cells! Also consider `For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.Range("D:I")` instead of `.Select` and then working against `Selection`. Rule of thumb, you NEVER need to `Select` or `Activate` anything in VBA.

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Range("D:I").Replace ",", "|"` : `ActiveSheet.Range("D:I").Replace ".", "."` : `ActiveSheet.Range("D:I").Replace "|", "."`

Answer (score 5):

`Replace` like you're using, is VBA's `VBA.Strings.Replace` function. That works, but as you've seen, when iterating 6 million individual cells, it takes a while.

Consider using [`Range.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace) instead, [as Scott showed in a comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57824683/replace-dot-with-comma-and-comma-with-dot#comment102079849_57824683) - that way you don't need to iterate anything; this should be much, much faster:

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("D:I")
    .Replace ",", "|" ' need a temp placeholder character, otherwise we'd end up with only commas!
    .Replace ".", ","
    .Replace "|", "."
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make three chances.

1. Change commas to something that is unique in your cell
2. Change dots to commas
3. Change that unique character to dots:

You can do this with one line of code where the inner most `Replace` is step `1`, the second most inner is step `2` and then outside `Replace` is step `3`.

```
Sub ReplacePointWithComma()

Dim Cell As Range

ActiveSheet.Range("D:I").Select

For Each Cell In Selection
    Cell.Value = Replace(Replace(Replace(Cell.Value, ",", "|"), ".", ","), "|", ".")
Next

End Sub
```

One other suggestion here is to not use `.Select` or `.Activate`. Humans select and activate cells and sheets, but VBA has no need for that. Just tell it which cells to act on:

```
Sub ReplacePointWithComma()

Dim Cell As Range

For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.Range("D:I").Cells
    Cell.Value = Replace(Replace(Replace(Cell.Value, ",", "|"), ".", ","), "|", ".")
Next

End Sub
```

Lastly, recognize that this is going to go through EVERY cell in columns D through I. Thats going to be 6 million iterations. Excel is doing it, but it's going to take forever. Instead give it a reasonable range to iterate through:

```
Sub ReplacePointWithComma()

Dim Cell As Range

For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.Range("D1:I10000").Cells
    Cell.Value = Replace(Replace(Replace(Cell.Value, ",", "|"), ".", ","), "|", ".")
Next

End Sub
```